# Using a JSON file to load an image in HTML

Tags: html, json

I am trying to use a json file to load an image, the image does load but the site keep getting a 404 error, this is how I'm loading the image in the html file.

```
...
<a ng-click="Ctrl.showProfile($event, $index)">
     <div class="imageWrapper-whatsapp">
          <img src={{user.avatar}}>
     </div>
...
```

And this is how the json file that I'm loading looks.

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "avatar": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
...
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message and perhaps the address associated with the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ng-src` instead of `src`.

```
<img ng-src="{{user.avatar}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with double quotes:

```
<img src="{{user.avatar}}"/>
```

See this:

```
<img ng-src={{user.avatar}}/>
```

When you add `/` near `}}` then the DOM will become `url/>`. the new `/` will search for new directory & throw 404 error Hence don't forget to add quotes.